# Computed Alias for sub controllers in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

This page, http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers explains how to manage dependencies between different controllers. The idea is that you put the controllers in the `needs` property, and if you want to assign a dependency controller on a property, you assign it using `Ember.computed.alias('controllers.controllername')`.

My problem is that I don't know the naming convention for aliases of sub-controllers. It's not in the docs, and I can't even find a single answer from Google about it. I might be using a wrong term when searching.  Sub-controllers usually accompany sub-routes.

Example, if you have a controller named `App.ProductController`, you know that its alias is `controllers.product`. But what if you have a sub-controller like `App.ProductEditController`? What is that alias for that? I tried using `controllers.product/edit` and it doesn't work. I'm using Ember 1.5.x.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried controllers.product_edit?

Comment: yup, or controllers.productEdit, both will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controllers.fooBar` or `controllers.foo_bar` will work

```
  needs:'fooBar',
  blah: Em.computed.alias('controllers.fooBar.blah')
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cifecoso/1/edit